# Use inequality from user input string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I'm writing a program that checks if input [ one number and equality statement ] compared against a randomly generated number is true, here's my code for reference:

```
import random

class Checker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_num=[]
        self.comp_roll()
        self.input_drive()
    def comp_roll(self):
        self.roll=random.randint(1,6)+random.randint(1,6) #roll 2 d6
    def input_drive(self):
        self.user_input=input("Input a number and [in]equality to compare against 2 random d6")
        user_input=self.user_input
        for i in range(len(user_input)):
            if user_input[i].isdigit() == True: #if user_input[i] is a num
                self.user_num.append(user_input[i]) #Keep track of just number from input in list
            else: #if user_input[i] is not a num
                if user_input[i] == ">":
                    self.track_op=">"
                elif user_input[i] == "<":
                    self.track_op="<"
                elif user_input[i] == "=":
                    self.track_op="="
        self.user_num=int("".join(self.user_num)) #turn number list into one int
        self.logic()
    def logic(self):
        dif=self.roll-self.user_num
        abs_dif=abs(dif)
        if self.track_op == ">":
            if dif > 0:
                win=True
            else:
                win=False
        elif self.track_op == "<":
            if dif < 0:
                win=True
            else:
                win=False
        elif self.track_op == "=":
            if dif == 0:
                win=True
            else:
                win=False
        print("{result}\nComputer Guessed %d\nYou Guessed %d\nDifference %d".format(result="Win! :)" if win==True else "Lose :(") % (self.roll,self.user_num,abs_dif))
test=Checker()
```

So as you should be able to see I'm forced to use a switch statement that individually checks the code to see if any of `>, <, =` exist.
I then have to save this as a string with the value of the equality sign.

```
    for i in range(len(user_input)):
        if user_input[i].isdigit() == True: #if user_input[i] is a num
            self.user_num.append(user_input[i]) #Keep track of just number from input in list
        else: #if user_input[i] is not a num
            if user_input[i] == ">":
                self.track_op=">"
            elif user_input[i] == "<":
                self.track_op="<"
            elif user_input[i] == "=":
                self.track_op="="
```

Which I then use in another switch statement to manually check the difference.

```
    dif=self.roll-self.user_num
    abs_dif=abs(dif)
    if self.track_op == ">":
        if dif > 0:
            win=True
        else:
            win=False
    elif self.track_op == "<":
        if dif < 0:
            win=True
        else:
            win=False
    elif self.track_op == "=":
        if dif == 0:
            win=True
        else:
            win=False
```

I would much rather save the [in]equality sign as a dictionary that uses a similar concept to this:

```
import operator
ops = { "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub }
```

I'm sure that there must be an quicker way to do this similar to the code above. I'm just not sure how to do it.

Thank you so much for the help! :)

Comment: `if user_input[i] in "<>=": self.track_op = user_input[i]`

Comment: Also, get out of the habit of `for i in range(len(user_input)):` and learn to use `for char in user_input:`

Comment: Excellent advice @Barmar ! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rarely need to use Boolean literals. Your switch first reduces to

```
if self.track_op == ">":
    win = dif > 0
elif self.track_op == "<":
    win = dif < 0
elif self.track_op == "=":
    win = dif == 0
```

which should make it obvious you can abstract out the comparison operators.

```
comp_ops = {">": operator.gt, "<": operator.lt, "=": operator.eq}
if self.track_op in comp_ops:
    win = comp_ops[self.trac_op](dif, 0)
```

Comment: Clever! I never thought of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason for avoiding the builtin `eval()` function? If not you could just do something like this in your checker class

```
import random

roll=random.randint(1,6)+random.randint(1,6)


print(roll)

test_in = input("please enter your statement")

try:
    test_out = eval(f"{test_in}roll")
    print(test_out)
except:
    print('Invalid Entry')
```

Results

```
10
please enter your statement>? 4>
False
```

And for a true statement

```
3
please enter your statement4>
True
```

Edit: I should add that `eval()` could be dangerous as it can execute arbitrary python commands. It doesn't seem like an issue in your case but I'd feel remiss if I didn't add an addendum

Comment: It completely slipped my mind. That makes things so much easier! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Please read my edit as I feel it is important to note.

Comment: Read. I assume eval() could open the program or computer up to vulnerabilities, yea?

Comment: "Is there a reason [to avoid] `eval`" Almost always.

Comment: Correct. You can add checks and other security measures to make sure you're evaluating what you want, but I would not use `eval()` on a public-facing program.